# Writing lots of JS injection code on a single chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way for making it easier to write a lot of code in a single chrome extension?
And is there a way to remove the first quotes in order to write simpler-to-view code?

I have this, and it's really annoying:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: '$("body").prepend("<div style='text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid black;'>123</div>")'
  });
});
```

I want to add lots of code to it but it's really difficult to read and edit when presented this way.

Comment: if you are beginer read [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your javascript code in a file and use:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'file.js'
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library yourself (unless you know it's available on the page).

Comment: @Halcyon Even if the page has jQuery, the extension cannot directly use it because of the separated [JavaScript execution contexts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is put the code to be executed in a function, call `toString` on the function, and then wrap it in an immediately invoked expression:

```
var code = '(' + injectFunction.toString() + ')();';
chrome.tabs.executeScript({ code: code });
```

Alternatively, you can use the file parameter to inject a file which contains your code:

```
 chrome.tabs.executeScript({ file: 'filtToInject.js' });
```